# Converting Oracle or Sql Server DDL to Derby

Tags: java, sql-server, oracle, derby, ddl

We have SQL Server/Oracle DDL but I'd like to use Derby for development/automated testing purposes.  I want a test env that I can sync to from source control and just run - no DB install BS.

Does anyone know a good way to convert either SQL Server or Oracle DDL to Apache Derby?

Comment: You are aware that this does not make a lot of sense. DDL is different for each DB system. Testing on a different database system than used for production is pretty much a wasted effort.

Comment: It makes all kinds of sense.  We would still test on a production DB after it passes the initial tests against Derby.  We have DB-agnostic code, it's just the DDL that is different (with a few exceptions).  SQL Server/Oracle setup is onerous and time consuming, and very difficult to script.  Derby is just a jar file.

Comment: Locking and performance behavior for each of these DB's will be very different. Its actually not difficult to script.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of an automated way to do it, but it shouldn't be too hard. If it were my, I'd just submit my SQL Server or Oracle DDL to a test Derby database and start looking at the errors.

Then I'd start writing a short program in my favorite scripting language to process the DDL and change the parts that Derby is complaining about to the syntax that Derby requires.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Liquibase](http://liquibase.org).

You can define your tables (and other DB objects) in a DBMS independent XML definition. Liquibase will then take care of creating the approriate DBMS-specific DDL for you.

If you need to target different DBMS with the same definition source, this is definitely something you should look at.